# Using Sid Steward's PDFTK in Windows receiving a Unhandled Java Exception: java.io.CharConversionException

Tags: pdftk

While attempting to find a way to merge existing PDF files and forms, I came across Sid Steward's [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and then found Andrew Heiss' PDFTK-php Class (code.google.com/p/pdftk-php/; www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/07/29/installing-pdftk-php/).  The idea seemed so simple, but when I tried it on my Windows 2003 Server and on my Windows XP virtual PC I get the same error trying to fill_form using a FDF generated form Andrew's example code.  I went ahead and changed Andrew's code around to see what the command line it was running.  Then typed this into a command prompt window to see the error.

The command line looks like this:
pdftk example.pdf fill_form fdf1b44.tmp output test.pdf flatten
(PDFTK is in my System PATH and all the other files are located in the current directory)
The example.pdf is generated as a 0KB file and an error pops up of:

### Unhandled Java Exception:

```
java.io.CharConversionException
 at 0x0056175e (Unknown Source)
 at 0x00561c52 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x00561d03 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0057692d (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0055f64d (Unknown Source)
 at 0x006bc0ad (Unknown Source)
 at 0x006994e0 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x00567a96 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0056e8f2 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0056e92c (Unknown Source)
 at 0x00445fa6 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0048b15e (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0048b5b8 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0048c238 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x0046c81f (Unknown Source)
 at 0x00469301 (Unknown Source)
 at 0x004666a6 (Unknown Source)
```

---

The results are identical for the Windows XP virtual pc and the Windows 2003 Server.  I've found very little on this issue and only possibly an entry that states Sid used a version of gcc to compile pdftk which had some poor java character support.  I downloaded Sid's Source files to take a look, but it truely is beyond my scope of knowledge.

Comment: Using PDFTK to merge the example.pdf to two other PDF files it works perfectly fine in generating the final merged file.  So something must be wrong with the way Andrew's PHP class is generating the FDF with my system setup.  I'll see what I can find out about the FDF file format and if the file is corrupt.

Comment: Okay, an old project of mine used the Adobe FDF Toolkit along with a template PDF file.  I coded that using ASP and ASP.NET and was trying to get away with using the Adobe FDF Toolkit in order to generate the FDF.  But I decided to check and save an FDF using the Adobe FDF Toolkit and then load it into the PDF using PDFTK to generate a flattened version of the document with the form fields filled out. 
objFdf.FDFSaveToFile "d:\Temp\test.fdf" and then used that file in the PDFTK command line:
pdftk template.pdf fill_form test.fdf output output.pdf flatten

Comment: Wallah the command line worked and the PDF is filled out and flattened.
So I guess my issue is with the way Andrew's PHP class (PDFTK-PHP) for handling PDFTK is generating the FDF file.  In Notepad++ looking at the FDF his generates verses the FDF from the Adobe FDF Toolkit it looks pretty similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on Andrew's site by Adam De Fouw.  Apparently the copy of PDFTK-PHP out there for download has a corrupt version of the example.pdf file.  So I wasn't the only one smacking my forehead trying to figure it out.  See Adam's answer(http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/07/29/installing-pdftk-php/) below:

Adam De Fouw  05/10/2010 10:24 PM in reply to Josh

http://pdftk-php.andrewheiss.com/example/exampl...

Use this example.pdf on Andrew's site instead of the version on GitHub. I was pulling my hair out for the past 2 hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working. Turned out that embedded Mac fonts were my nemesis, as Andrew alluded to.

Use that PDF, and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Arachnid, you made my day. Your solution worked perfectly for me on my Windows XP test environment. 
Here is the full link to the example.pdf, clickable:

http://pdftk-php.andrewheiss.com/example/example.pdf

I added this as an issue to the pdftk-php github page, too.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same error using PDFtk and my own PHP code (not pdftk-php) to do an FDF/PDF merge. I spent two days trying to figure it out. I modified my code to merge the fields one by one and report back with the specific fields that caused the error--as some of them worked fine and others didn't. Upon inspecting the diffs between the fields that caused errors and the fields that didn't, I realized the fields that caused errors were set to OpenSans font. The fields that worked were set to Times Roman. Once I changed all fields to use Times Roman instead of OpenSans, PDFtk quit throwing the error. I hope my two days of head banging helps someone someday.